# Calculating year end balance and year end interest with compound interest

Tags: c++, banking

I am trying to create a function that calculates year end balance and year end interest based on the monthly deposits and monthly interests that accumulate in the year. For some reason, it is not outputting the correct numbers. Whenever I input 1 for investment, 50 for monthly deposit, %5 for annual interest, and 5 for years. It should output:

Year   Year End Balance   Year End Earned Interest

1       $617.55               $16.55

2       $1265.65               $48.10

3       $1946.90               $81.25

4       $2663.01               $116.11

5       $3415.76               $152.75

Instead, it is outputting:

Year   Year End Balance   Year End Earned Interest

1       $600.76               $0.16

2       $1205.65               $0.63

3       $1817.61               $1.39

4       $2440.90               $2.45

5       $3078.92               $3.82

Can someone help with function reportWithMonthlyPay()?

Here is the code I have currently:

```
// BankingApp.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and 
ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Bank {
public: 
    void dataInput();
    void displayInput();
    void reportWithoutMonthlyPay();
    void reportWithMonthlyPay();

private:
    double investment;
    double deposit;
    int years;
    double interest;
    double monthly_interest;
    double monthly_balance;
    double year_end_balance;
    double year_end_interest;
    vector<int> month_numbers;
    vector<int> year_numbers;
};

void Bank::dataInput() {
    cout << "Initial Investment Amount: " << endl;
    cin >> investment;
    cout << "Monthly Deposit: " << endl;
    cin >> deposit;
    cout << "Annual Interest: " << endl;
    cin >> interest;
    cout << "Number of years: " << endl;
    cin >> years;
    system("pause");       // Windows-specific command that tells 
platform to pause 
program
    cout << endl;
    if (cin.get()) {        // If any key is entered, displayInput 
 function is called
        displayInput();     
    }

}

void Bank::displayInput() {
    cout << "Initial Investment Amount: " << "$" << investment << 
 endl;
    cout << "Monthly Deposit: " << "$" << deposit << endl;
    cout << "Annual Interest: " << interest << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Number of years: " << years << endl;
    system("pause");
    cout << endl;
    reportWithoutMonthlyPay();
   }

  void Bank::reportWithoutMonthlyPay() {
    year_numbers.resize(years);
    interest = interest / 100;
    year_end_balance = investment + (investment * interest);
    year_end_interest = investment * interest;
     cout << "   Balance and Interest Without Additional Monthly 
 Deposit   " << endl;
    cout << "=============================================================" << 
  endl;
    cout << "Year    Year End Balance    Year End Earned Interest" 
  << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < year_numbers.size(); i++) {
        year_numbers[i] = i + 1; 
        cout << year_numbers[i] << "        $" << fixed << 
  setprecision(2) << 
    year_end_balance << "               $" << year_end_interest << 
  endl;
        year_numbers[i]++;
        year_end_balance += year_end_interest;
        year_end_interest = year_end_balance * interest;
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    reportWithMonthlyPay();
}

 void Bank::reportWithMonthlyPay() {
 year_numbers.resize(years);
 month_numbers.resize(12);
 year_end_interest = 0;
 year_end_balance = investment;
  cout << "   Balance and Interest With Additional Monthly Deposit   
  " << endl;
   cout << 
  "==========================================================" << 
 endl;
   cout << "Year     Year End Balance   Year End Earned Interest" 
  << endl;
   cout << "------------------------------------------------------- 
---" << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < year_numbers.size(); i++) {
       year_numbers[i] = i + 1;
       for (int j = 0; j < month_numbers.size(); j++) {
        year_end_balance += deposit;
        monthly_interest = year_end_balance * (interest / 
(double)12);
        year_end_balance += monthly_interest;
        year_end_interest += monthly_interest;
        month_numbers[j]++;
    }
    cout << year_numbers[i] << "        $" << fixed << 
   setprecision(2) << year_end_balance << "               $" << 
   year_end_interest << endl;
    year_numbers[i]++;
   }

int main()
{
    Bank userInput;

    userInput.dataInput();
}
```

Comment: what did you see when you walked through with the debugger

Comment: The program exited with code 0

Comment: use the debugger to walk through the program. watch the variables, make sure they are correct. Set a breakpoint right here `year_numbers[i] = i + 1; ` for example

Comment: I am getting some build errors saying the variables before line 26 are uninitialized.

Comment: so fix that then

Comment: I took out the 100 in the interest calculation in reportWithMonthlyPay function because interest was being divided twice due to it being divided in previous function. Now, all number for year end balance are correct, but only the first number for year end earned interest is correct.

Comment: use your debugger to step through the code, I could do that but it would better if you did, single step and watch all the variables

Comment: whats the initial amount i should use? you say 1 in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241764/discussion-between-gman12-and-pm100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, well i run your code and its all over the place. inputting 1,50,5,5 as entered in the question is doesnt do any monthly payment processing  because it only calls `reportWithoutMonthlyPay`

If I change the code to call `reportWithMonthlyPay` the output is nothing like you show. So then I fixed one line and the output is close

```
            monthly_interest = year_end_balance * (interest /  (double)1200);
```

in reportWithMonthy. Ie scale down interest by 100.

output is

```
Year     Year End Balance   Year End Earned Interest
-------------------------------------------------------  -- -
1        $617.55               $16.55
2        $1265.65               $64.65
3        $1946.90               $145.90
4        $2663.01               $262.01
5        $3415.76               $414.76
```

still not like what you gave as expected output but closer. I leave it to you to find out why

OK cracked that too. You need to reset year_end_interes to 0 for each year loop in reportWithMonthlyPay. When I do that

```
==========================================================
Year     Year End Balance   Year End Earned Interest
-------------------------------------------------------  -- -
1        $617.55               $16.55
2        $1265.65               $48.10
3        $1946.90               $81.25
4        $2663.01               $116.11
5        $3415.76               $152.75
```

so A for me on the assignment